# Rewrite $2 +\cdots + ( n-1) + n +(n-1)\cdot 2$ (possible error?)

Tags: calculus, summation, algorithms

This is from a book (regarding an analysis  of selction sort), but isn't there an error between line $2$ and $3$?

> \begin{align}
> n + &(n-1) + \cdots + 2 + (n-1)\cdot 2 \tag 1\\
> &= 2 +\cdots + ( n-1) + n +(n-1)\cdot 2 \tag 2\\
> &=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} -1 +(n-1)\cdot 2 \tag 3
> \end{align}
>   where 
>   \begin{align}
> 1 + 2 + \cdots (n-1) + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \tag 4
> \end{align}

My attempt:

From line $2$ we have
\begin{align}
2 +\cdots + &( n-1) + n +(n-1)\cdot 2 \\
& = 2 + \cdots + 2n -1 +(n-1) \cdot 2 \tag 5
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
2 + \cdots 2n = 2(1+2+ \cdots +n) = 2 \tag 6\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
\end{align}
So from line $5$ we end up with
\begin{align}
n(n+1) -1 +(n-1)\cdot 2 \tag 7
\end{align}

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final $2$ is multiplied by only $(n-1)$, not by all the terms in the sum.

$2+\cdots+(n-1)+n+\color{green}{(n-1)\cdot2}$

$=\underbrace{\color{blue}1+2+\cdots+(n-1)+n}-\color{blue}1+\color{green}{(n-1)\cdot2}$

$=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2-1+\color{green}{(n-1)\cdot2}$

Comment: So the trick was just to add and remove 1 ( blue color)?

Comment: Yes, so the well-known formula for $1+2+\cdots+n$ could be employed